# Motion Tracking video tips

Tags: video, tracking, motion-capture

I just started with motion tracking in blender and it a really awesome feature but I discovered that shooting the right video is very hard.

The image below is a part of I test video I made where I moved my phone from left to right and than to the left again. Like you can see on the image, all the tracking points on the left are useless for blender and it is really hard to works with only the right part of the video.

My question is: **has somebody tips about how to shoot a good video for motion tracking?**

Should you just walk around an object with some good marks instead of moving the camera from left to right like I did.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to give an answer to the question as it stands. What is it that you are trying to achieve? moving form left to right will give  you no parallax information, is that what you are after? Trackers can be joined if the same feature comes back into the picture..

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8969/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/how-to-pick-good-keyframes-for-motion-tracking

Comment: @poor http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/947/599

Comment: @cegaton I asked this question because like you can see on the picture are some trackers not useful for blender. Is filming from the left to the right not good for motion tracking because of this problem or has somebody a tip for shooting a good video where the camera moves from the left to the right.

Comment: when you move the camera and the object you are tracking goes out of the frame then the tracking stops (and that is is what those boxes on the edges represent). It doesn't mean that those trackers are useless, it just means that are not active on this particular frame.

Comment: @cegaton So if the trackers leave the screen at for example frame 30 than can I go to frame 30 and hit detect trackers so that blender can find some trackers at the right part.

Comment: It's better if you manually select the points you want to track.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14713/1853

Comment: @cegaton thanks for the link, it looks very useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31604/discussion-between-cegaton-and-vinc199789).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to shoot a video is either by using a tripod and not turning the camera, which means you almost need to do no motion tracking at all, or you film it by hand and try to do it as smoothly as possible, any blurry frames mess up your trackers. or you just don't do motion tracking at all and try to animate the camera into the same position in the 3D viewport.

Comment: There is a limitation if you keep the camera on a tripod. By not displacing the camera you will get no parallax information. Without it there is no way to do a proper 3d reconstruction. The Default solver needs displacement (the camera moving, not only rotating). Solving the scene as "tripod" will only project the trackers in a spherical way around the camera. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332