# Set range of keyframes for motion tracking

Tags: tracking

I'm trying to make a scene with camera tracking and I need my camera to move from left to right. As a result, some of my trackers get "lost" when they are near the edge of the scene. I want to ask if there is a way to set a range of keyframes for each tracker to use and then stop working.

When a tracker gets too close to the edge of the screen instead of stop tracking, it starts to move in weird ways, as if it is still trying to track the given point in the video.

The image bellow shows that weird movement of the tracker:

[image: The point which is supposed to be tracked is in the orange circle]

Comment: When the tracker gets too close to the edge of the frame and there is no more reliable data to track, the tracking process stops automatically. You could set the section to be tracked manually by shifting the start and end points of the video clip. But I'm unclear if that is what you need. Please edit your question and add additional information. A few images may help to understand the problem. Additionally you can offset the trackers once they reach the edge of the frame. See if this posts helps you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset

Comment: For more info on motion tracking read this posts: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/motion-tracking-my-model-zooms-in-or-out-or-is-sliding/42332#42332 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14713/1853

Comment: Your tracker seems to be slipping. Why? Tracking works best with elements that are clear and different than the rest of the surrounding pixels. In this case a large area of the image (the road) has few distinct elements to track. You are probably getting false positives. Pick other points to track but not only on the ground, you have plenty of points on the rocks on the wall, the curb, etc. You need at least 8 successful trackers for reconstruction, but do not limit yourself to 8, Track a lot more and let blender decide which are the most useful and accurate.

Comment: Also, try different tracking **motion** settings other than Loc. Use LocRotScale or Perspective.

Comment: For a comprehensive post on motion tracking read: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)