# Blender using disabled tracking points, when motion-tracking

Tags: tracking

I have noticed, that when I track a point in video, and it runs bad, and I therefore disable it with the "disable/enable eye", then is that point still used, when "solving camera".

For instance. I have a scene with 1000 frames and 20 tracking points.
Track.015 runs bad because what it tracks in the video gets behind something at frame 750, and I solve the camera, gets an solve error at 2.7563. I go to the frame, where the point got lost, and disables it by clicking the eye in the panel there show/hidden by pressing **"n"**, and solves again, still solve error: 2.7563.
But if I instead goes to the frame, where the point get lost and clicks *"Clear track after current position"* and clicks solve again, I suddenly get a solve error at 1.3402 instead.

This is no a big problem, if the rest of the tracking is bad. But I have also points there are bad somewhere in the middle of the clip, and that I have spend a good while tracking good, when the points again get visible. I disabled them, for the time, where they are bad, and enabled them again, when they are good again.. But I see now, that they still mess up the camera, because they are being used also for the time, where they are disabled.

Is there something I can do, to make Blender not use those points, while they are disabled?
Or clear part of tracking like from frame 450 to frame 500, instead of clearing all after current frame? (that could also solve the problem, but I prefer to be able to use the disable-function, as it often could be nice to temporary disable a point to see, if it makes things better or worse).

(I am currently using Blender v2.76, I don't know, if this might be a bug in that version?)

Comment: use weighted tracking (see [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14704/camera-tracking-moving-the-camera-too-much/14705#14705)

Comment: for tips on tracking read this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332 tip#2 might help you find and fix the segments where inaccurate tracking is occurring

Comment: I have the same issue, the track point is usable at the beginning then goes bad, weighted is not suitable I am looing for other solution