# Motion tracking stops at a certain frame before the end of the shot

Tags: video, tracking

I have 7223 frames to track, I set my track mark it only goes to 762 then stops. Even though it does not do that usual thing when it loses it mark, I still reset the mark, then go one frame at a time, and it is not tracking it. 
as you see it does not lose the track it just stops and will not go any further.

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Check that the media is actually the right length then generate Timecode/proxy from it. This will help Blender read the video file you are using. Sometimes a heavily compressed file is hard for Blender to read back correctly.

Comment: I broke it down into png files, then selected just the first one, first time trying to do it this way, youtube vids have been saying this is how to do it. then it automatically selects the rest of the images in sequence. so no proxy can be used off images. time frames all match

Comment: Umm, you should be able to create a proxy still, anyway it sounds like you're hitting a memory issue. Move Clip editor should be able to dump frames as it goes. Notice the line that builds as you play or track thru? Can you scrub past this point?

Answer (score 4):

If the tracker is very close to the edge, the automatic tracking will stop. It cannot keep tracking if there are no pixels to fill the tracked area.
Either [**offset**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28826/3710) the marker (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) or create a new one and [**join**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14713/3710) both, else you can manually position the tracker for any given frame.

Comment: thanks - made it smaller, but now to learn how to join/merge. So you wouldn't know the keyboard shortcut to track one frame at a time would you? anyone? google just gives me more information then I need when searching that question.

Comment: Alt+Left/Right arrow willl track one frame in the irectionof the arrow... In many cases, to find the keyboard shortcut just move the mouse so that the cursor hovers over the tool you need, and a small window will appear with a tooltip message (make sure the tooltips box is enabled in the  user preferences) **To ask new questions please use a different post**.

Comment: sorry I was trying to save electronic paper.

Comment: You can ask as many questions as you want (each one on a different post) Think of it this way: Someone looking for information on how to find the keyboard shortcut for a particular tool has no idea that the information is on a question for motion tracking.... should I google B when I'm really looing for A?